# how to generate error message in form if any of the fields left blank

Tags: javascript, forms

```
     <form onsubmit="chkform()">
        <table>
        <tr><td>name</td><td><input type="text" id="uname"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><div id="er1"></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>address</td><td><input type="text" id="add"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><div id="er2"></div></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
     <script>   
            function chkform()
            {


              if (document.getElementById("uname").value === "" ) 
              {

               document.getElementById("er1").innerHTML = "name cant be left blank"; 
               document.getElementById("er1").style.color = "red"; 
               document.getElementById("er1").style.display = "block"; 
              }
        }
</script>
```

i want to show  error message in div, if any of the fields are left blank and this message should disappear when text box is clicked.

Comment: I don't see any submit `button`.

Comment: Why the upvotes? I assume you don't want the message "name cant be left blank" to appear if the address field is empty? have you tried anything else? Also most devs haven't used tables for layout purposes since last century

Comment: @andrew "... since last century" is unnecessarily derisive hyperbole.

Comment: You could use `<td id="er1"></td></tr>` instead of `<td><div id="er2"></div></td>` if it for error messages only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <form onsubmit="return false">
        <table>
        <tr><td>name</td><td><input type="text" id="uname"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><div id="er1"></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>address</td><td><input type="text" id="add"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><div id="er2"></div></td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" onclick="chkform()"/>
        </form>
     <script>   
            function chkform()
            {


              if (document.getElementById("uname").value === "" ) 
              {

               document.getElementById("er1").innerHTML = "name cant be left blank"; 
               document.getElementById("er1").style.color = "red"; 
               document.getElementById("er1").style.display = "block"; 
              }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following will always allow you to add `input`s without re-writing your validation function:

```
function chkform()
{
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].value === '')
            // do your error
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muRbe/)**</kbd>

Comment: `if(inputs[i].value === '')` should most likely be `if((inputs[i].type=="text"||inputs[i].type=="password") && inputs[i].value === '' )` or something of the sort

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need `return` to

```
<form onsubmit="return chkform()">
```

and

`return false` in your red alert message block

that works.

i.e.

```
<form onsubmit="return chkform()">
```

```
function chkform() {
  if (document.getElementById("uname").value === "") {
    . . .
    return false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("car").value == "truck") {
    . . .
    return false;
  }
  . . .
}
```

Comment: don't take this as a negative comment, but why `onclick` of the `button` and why not `onsubmit` of `form`?

Comment: Note that this wont work with other ways of submitting, eg. hitting the enter key inside a field.

Comment: I agree, but in what field pressing enter will trigger the whole form to sumit?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding both input boxes to an array, and looping through them to test whether they have values entered or not.

I've edited your code.

```
function chkform()
                {

    var inputs = [];
    inputs[0] = document.getElementById("uname");
    inputs[1] = document.getElementById("add");

    for( i =0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

                  if (inputs[i].value === "" ) 
                  {

                   document.getElementById("er1").innerHTML = "Please fill out all form inputs!"; 
                   document.getElementById("er1").style.color = "red"; 
                   document.getElementById("er1").style.display = "block"; 
                  }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add else part to your if condition, that will take care of removing the error message when thge field has been filled.

```
else {
              document.getElementById("er1").innerHTML = ""; 
              document.getElementById("er1").style.display = "none";
              }
```

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxJid**